# How to perform multi-column joins in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have 2 tables in Power query editor.

The relationship between both is based on 3 columns.

However, the merge allows me to only join based on 1 column.

What is the way to perform merge based on 3 column? For example - append the 3 columns into 1 and then merge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do multi column joins in power query. Just hold control key and click each column that should be part of the join.

Comment: Make sure to click the columns on each table in the same order!